# unsigned int tot_len:16; returns different result to uint16_t

Tags: c++

As far as I can see, an unsigned int with specified length should be equivalent to uintxx_t if the sizes are equivalent. However when I point a struct with these members to an area in memory to observe the fields, the values are different. Specifically, I'm examining ip header fields. Using unsigned int tot_len:16; returns the correct result, whereas setting the field to uint16_t returns an incorrect value. gcc/g++ 4.5.2 is being used on a windows platform. Could anyone explain what is happening?

The faulty struct definition:

```
typedef struct ip4 {
 #if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN    
  unsigned int ihl :4;  
  unsigned int version :4; 
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN  
  unsigned int version:4;   
  unsigned int ihl:4; #else
# error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
 #endif     uint8_t tos;    
  uint16_t tot_len;     
  uint16_t id;  
  uint16_t frag_off; // flags=3 bits, offset=13 bits    
  uint8_t ttl;  
  uint8_t protocol;     
  uint16_t check;   
  uint32_t saddr;   
  uint32_t daddr;   
/*The options start here. */
 } ip4_t;
```

The struct works when all the uintxx_t are switched with the unsigned int xxx:xx equivalents. In other words, *all* values with uintxx_t are incorrect. When switched with unsigned int xxx:xx, the values are now correct.  (I am trying to fix some issues with a third party library that my work is using, so I can't provide an entirely reproducible example. The calling method:

```
void scan_ip4(register scan_t *scan) {      
    header_t *eth;      
    if ((scan->buf_len - scan->offset) < sizeof(ip4_t)) {   
        return;     
    }  
    register ip4_t *ip4 = (ip4_t *) (scan->buf + scan->offset);
    uint16_t tot_len = BIG_ENDIAN16(ip4->tot_len); 
    scan->length = ip4->ihl * 4; 
    scan->hdr_payload = tot_len - scan->length;
    if (is_accessible(scan, 8) == FALSE) {
        return;
    }
  ....

}
```

Comment: Show the code, please.  This needs a [mcve].

Comment: It doesn't matter what you *think* the representation should be. The compiler is free to do what it wants, and `reinterpret_cast`ing around that is only going to lead to nightmares. At a first guess, I'd say `uint16_t` probably has some padding that a bitfield doesn't, but that's a guess without being able to see what you're doing. Have you used `sizeof` on the two structs to see if padding is being added to one?

Comment: " when I point a struct with these members to an area in memory" rings warning bells about the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Yeah, seeing the edit in this question, I'm increasingly convinced the whole thing is a strict aliasing violation as Nate suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately, this library is being used to generate data that over several hundred papers have published on - the library is old and unmaintained, and is generating faulty data sporadically. With your comments I think I have a better idea of the issue at hand, but my hands are tied and I'm seeing if I can patch in a fix to address that issue (which is not in this question)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, the struct sizes are different. I believe your hypothesis regarding padding being applied to the uint16_t and not to unsigned int tot_len:16 is correct, many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will provide an updated the answer with more information for others who might be running into the same problem shortly

Answer (score 1):

```
    typedef struct ip4 {
     #if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN        
      unsigned int ihl :4;      
      unsigned int version :4;     
    #elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN      
      unsigned int version:4;       
      unsigned int ihl:4;     #else
    # error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
     #endif
      uint8_t tos;        
      uint16_t tot_len;         
    ...
```

Here you define a bitfield using `unsigned int` as storage and place 2 4bit values in it. The remaining 24 bit are padded out. `tos` is then at offset 4 followed by another padding byte and `tot_len` is at offset 6.

```
    typedef struct ip4 {
     #if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN        
      unsigned int ihl :4;      
      unsigned int version :4;     
    #elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN      
      unsigned int version:4;       
      unsigned int ihl:4;     #else
    # error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
     #endif
      unsigned int tos:8;        
      unsigned int tot_len:16;         
    ...
```

Here you place all 4 variables into the bitfield using a single 32bit unsigned int. So `tos` is at offset 1 and `tot_len` is at offset 2.
Or the bitfield is layed out the other way and `tot_len` is at offset 0, `tos` at offset 2 and the rest at offset 3. Bitfield layout is implementation defined.

---

If you want only `ihl` and `version` as bitfield then you have to define it at `uint8_t ihl : 4; uint8_t version : 4;` so only a single byte is used as storage for the bitfield.

You should `static_assert(sizeof(ip4) == <expected size>);`